# React project with Axios config problem with return data. Data are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am using axios in react project. I am creating the class for api call with axios.
I am creating axios config for reusing.
In the first api.js console.log show  data. But in subject.js data is undefined. I tried rewritte method getData as async but in subject.js I have got The 'await' operator can only be used in an 'async' function. So I looking another way.

```
//class api.js :

    getInstance(isAuthorized = null)
    {
        if(this.instance == null)
        {
            if(isAuthorized)
            {

                this._headers = {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.authManager.getToken()}`
                };
            }

            if(isAuthorized == null)
            {
                this._headers = {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                };
            }

            this.instance =  axios.create({
                baseURL: this.baseUrl,
                timeout: 1000,
                headers: this._headers
            });

            return this.instance;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.instance;
        }
    }


    getData(action,payload,isAuthorized) {

        try {
            let data = undefined;

            this.getInstance(isAuthorized).get(action).then(response =>{
                data = response.data;
                // here its ok data initialized
                console.log(data);

                return data;
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    }
//class subject.js
    export default () => {
        const api = new Api();
    
        // console log writte undefined
        console.log(api.getData('/subject/get',null,true));
    ....
```

Comment: You should make your getInstance function asyc and put await before axios.Create, this also does not fix your problem because your in your subject.js the console.log probably logs a promise after you fixed the first issue, right?